# Best Practice to store Azure WebJob Logs incl. Data in Azure

Tags: azure, logging, azure-webjobs

I have several Azure WebJobs (.Net Framework, Not .Net Core) running which interact with an Azure Service Bus. Now I want to have a convenient way to store and analyze their Log-Messages (incl. the related Message from the Service Bus). We are talking about a lot of Log Messages per Day.

My Idea is to send the Logs to an Azure Event Hub and store them in an Azure SQL Database. Later I can have for example a WebApp that enables Users to conveniently browse and analyze the Logs and view the Messages.

Is this a bad Idea? Should I instead use Application Insights?

Comment: Can you define what a 'lot' of log messages is?  How many messages per second and how much total data.  Also, will analysis of the logs be simple lookups or complex queries?  This will help determine how the messages should be processed (i.e. EventHub) and how they should be stored (i.e .sql server, azure tables).

Answer (score 0):

Application insight charges are more than your implementation. So i would say this is good idea. Just one change i would send each logs to logic apps and do some processing like sorting error logs, info logs etc differently. Also why are you thinking about SQL when this can be stored in non SQL Azure tables and fetch them from there.